# How do I get 3 stars in Mario Kart 7?

Tags: mario-kart-7

How do I get 3 stars in Mario Kart 7? I have got 3 stars in the 50 and 100cc races, but I can't seem to get it on Mirror Mode and 150cc. I have also seen many other people ask about this, and the answers are always different. Does anyone have a legit answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need a good positioning.

According to [NintenPedia:](https://nintenpedia.com/forum/threads/best-kart-setup-in-mario-kart-7.481/)

> Yeah, Metal Mario, B-Dasher, Red Wheels, and Peach's Parasol is the best combination for no item races. But I think Daisy, B-Dasher, Red Wheels, and Peach's Parasol is the best combination for item races, as this combination is strong in both acceleration and speed.

You need to avoid items as well, giving you a better chance to get 1st place, therefore, drifting can help too.

---

Secondly, you need the best car for 150cc, meaning, that you need the fastest car, **but you need to be careful if you are on a falling map.**

According to [Reddit,](https://www.reddit.com/r/mariokart/comments/4xqrrc/what_is_the_fastest_kart_in_mario_kart_7_if_you/) these are fastest cars:

> In regards to karts; yes, the bodies with the highest speed are Zuchinni, Blue Seven, Growlster and B Dasher.

---

Last of all, you need a good character.

According to [IGN,](https://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-7/Rosalina) Rosalina is a decent character:

> Rosalina has an advantage bonus for weight, and for speed and off-road.

---

Due to all of these tips, you should be able to get 3 stars in Mario Kart 7 150cc.

Answer (score 2):

Searching on [gamespot](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/3ds/997822-mario-kart-7/answers/303974-how-do-i-get-a-3-stars-rating) here is the answer i can find.

Its mostly theories but it seems to be related to

- at least getting 40 points
- not falling off stage
- not going offroad

I would guess the first one is most probable, the second one is possible, and the third I have doubts about (it would require them to program a huge thing that checks if you are on or offroad and that seems a lot of work for an accessory thing like stars completion. But I'm going via feeling right now.)

Also, it seems that this question is a duplicata: [What's the formula for getting 3-stars in a cup?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127323/whats-the-formula-for-getting-3-stars-in-a-cup/127350)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get 1st in every race (which is hard sometimes) You also need to stay on road as much  as possible. Try not to go out of bounds. This has worked for me. It will hopefully help you (: